# crear tabla con procedimiento almacenado

Tags: stored-procedure

Estoy intentando crear una tabla con el nombre de un parametro dado a un `store procedure:`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INTENTO3 
    @table varchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN  
    create table @table 
    ( 
        campo1 varchar(20) 
    ) 
END
```

Me sale siempre el **error**:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure INTENTO3, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 1]
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@table'

Comment: Saludos aquí hay una [buena respuesta SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877522/8933039) que te puede resolver el problema y ayudarte en más cosas. (Traducir del Inglés).

Answer (score 1):

En `mySQL` no se le puede pasar el nombre de la tabla como parámetro. Necesitas utilizar Dynamic SQL.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `create_tb_one`(In tableName varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @table_exists
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND table_name=tableName;

    IF @table_exists = 0 THEN
        SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',tableName,' ');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'(ID INT NOT NULL,SNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'SSTATE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'TIME_STAMP VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'constraint FK_SENSOR ');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'foreign key (SNAME) ');
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'references sensorInfo(SName) on delete set null)');
        PREPARE s FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE s;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Fuente](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112827/how-can-we-create-a-table-from-stored-procedure?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

En SQL Server yo haría algo como esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Crear_Tabla] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@nombreTabla varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
   Execute ('Create TABLE '+@nombreTabla+'(id int, nombre varchar(50))')
END
```

Espero te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Thanks Peter! So the solution to this particular problem:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createTable(IN tableName VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
SET @table := tableName;
SET @sql_text:=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@table,'(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, FILENAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, DATA BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))');

PREPARE stmt from @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

In addition to the manual I also found a very helpful tut by Roland Bouman at:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.htmlenter code here

El autor de la respuesta: Conrad Ljungström

link de la respuesta original: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,495352

Comment: Porque escribis una respuesta en ingles a una pregunta en español, en un sitio en español.

Answer (score -1):

puedes intentar con algo asi:(mysql)

```
 delimiter |
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_TABLE_TEST ()
       BEGIN
          CREATE TABLE TEST 
          (
            TestID int(11) default NULL,
            TestName varchar(100) default NULL
          ) 
          ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
       END;

    |
```

Comment: El PO pide crear una tabla pasándole el nombre como parámetro. Y ya que estamos podías citar tu fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100669/stored-procedures-that-creates-a-table